# ServiceNow Sharing Dashboard

Tags: servicenow

I have 2 team members that have access to all the same things as I do. When I attempt to share a created dashboard, there names/emails are unavailable, why would this be?

Comment: can you share the list of roles under your user account and your team member's account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to *Performance Analytics > Dashboard Admin*.
2. Click a dashboard to open it.
3. Choose from the following options in the *Visible to field*:

**Everyone**:   Select roles that can access this dashboard.

**Users and Groups**:   Select users and groups that can access the dashboard.

Also note that, users must have the **`pa_viewer`** role to view dashboards. Users with the **`pa_admin`** and **`pa_power_user`** roles can create and edit dashboards.

[Read more about Dashboards here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-performance-analytics-and-reporting/page/use/dashboards/reference/dashboards-landing-page.html)